# Testing a function without a parameter and using moq and xunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm trying to write a unit test for a function:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPerson()
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Person";
    using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
    {
        var person = await connection.QueryAsync<Person>(query);
        return person.ToList();
    }
}
```

which is in the `PersonServices` class and inherits from the `IPersonServices` interface.

Test:

```
[Fact]
public void TestGetPersonReturnPerson()
{
    var mocGetPerson = new Mock<IPersonServices>();
    mocGetPerson.Setup(m => m.GetPerson().Result).Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Person>>) ;
    IPersonServices personServices = mocGetPerson.Object;

    Assert.NotNull(personServices);
}
```

Test fails...

Comment: Use `ReturnsAsync` method.

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution:

```
private static List<Person> GetFakePersonList()
 {
     return new List<Person>()
    {  
  new Person
     {
         Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
         dateTimeCreate = DateTime.Now,
         Email = "email@gmail.com",
         FirstName = "xxx",
         LastName = "xxx",
         Password = "123123"
     } 
     };
 }

 [Fact]
 public async Task TestGetPersonReturnPerson()
 {
     var mocGetPerson = new Mock<IPersonServices>();
     mocGetPerson.Setup(m => m.GetPerson().Result).Returns(PersonControllerTest.GetFakePersonList);
     var result = mocGetPerson.Object.GetPerson();

     Assert.NotNull(result);
 }
```

Comment: Please try to provide some explanation as well.